# Hide Result set of sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, temp-tables, dynamicquery, sp-executesql

I am trying to run `sp_executesql` but I don't want to show the results in resultset and I can't use variables because my stored procedure calls different datasources. So I am not able to create single table what should I do? Any suggestions?

```
--INSERT INTO #TEMP  this what i want but didn't work i know

EXECUTE sp_executesql  @SQL,  N'@ENTITYID INT,@REPORTINGDATE DATE,@PREVIOUSREPORTINGDATE DATE',   
                                @ENTITYID    ,@REPORTINGDATE     ,@PREVIOUSREPORTINGDATE 

                
SET @tempSQL = 'SELECT '+@Select+' INTO #TEMP FROM ##TEMP '+@GROUPBY+' DROP TABLE ##TEMP '
```

This isn't working for me `SET NOEXEC ON`   because it just compile not execute and in my query I am using `##temp`.

This is my query

```
select A , B , SUM(C)
into ##temp
FROM
        #tempp
GROUP BY
        A , B 

select * from ##temp
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEnQM.png)
don't want first result set

Comment: If you don't want a result set returned, why do you have a `SELECT` in it? Amend the SQL to not return a result set, and you don't get a result set. This smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: *"This isn't working for me `SET NOEXEC ON` because it just compile not execute "* That's what `NOEXEC` is supposed to do. From [SET NOEXEC (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-noexec-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): *"Compiles each query but does not execute it."*

Comment: You can just add variable @debug in your procedure and if execute with parameter =1 only show selects inside

Comment: I am using select into below query .
@Larnu 
EXECUTE sp_executesql  @ SQL,  N'@ ENTITYID INT,@ REPORTINGDATE DATE,@PREVIOUSREPORTINGDATE DATE',   
@ ENTITYID  ,@ REPORTINGDATE  ,@ PREVIOUSREPORTINGDATE 
    
SET @ tempSQL = 'SELECT '+@ Select+' INTO # TEMP FROM ## TEMP '+@ GROUPBY+' DROP TABLE ## TEMP '

Comment: @HakimChandio  [edit] your question to include attempts; don't put them in the comments.

Comment: Also, I hope the columns you are injecting into that query are properly delimit identified.

Comment: So, the above statement *won't* return a data set, due to the `INTO`.

Comment: @Larnu thanks for guide i am using first time.

Comment: Start at the beginning: what are you actually trying to do? You haven't shown us your full code, where does `##temp` come from?

Answer (score 0):

You can add parameter like @debug inside your procedure and do selects only if you execute procedure with @debug =1

What i mean you procedure should looks like :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[History]
(
@Id_user NVARCHAR(450),
@debug int
)
AS

BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON


begin tran az


if(@debug) =1
begin
select 'A', 'B' from yourtable where id = @Id_user
end


commit tran az

 
END
```

and execute procedure with `debug = 0` will not show your select .

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[History]
        @Id_user = '122',
        @debug  =0
```

And later you can play with you data like that :

```
DECLARE @tempTable  TABLE(
            ID_user  VARCHAR(100)
            
    )
    

  INSERT INTO @tempTable 
  EXEC  @return_value = [dbo].[History]
        @Id_user = '122',
        @debug  =0


        select * from @tempTable
```

Comment: But its necessary to execute sp_executesql because after that my data save in ##temp then i will further play with data hope you understand .
 @Adamszsz

Comment: Edited answear , you can create later Temp table , and then do insert into with executed procedure - i think that was what you looking for - there is idea only .You need to to do with your data just. And ofc - with debug = 0 the procedure will not return now data :P . Let me know if it helps you or i can delete just answear